Remove item in array not include substring
I have a string like this
let myarr = ['A511-0001-01', 'APWA-0001-03', 'APWA-9999-99'];

and i have a substring to filter myarr like AP.
let filteringCondition = 'AP';

how can i get myarr to (remove 'A511-0001-01') with Javascript?
Expected result:
myarr = ['APWA-0001-03', 'APWA-9999-99'];

Thanks for read. Im newbie
i don't know to try with this specs

myarr.filter(x => x.startsWith('AP'))

Will you always be removing the exact same string?

are we talking about strings or arrays? question's title and body mismatch

is the AP always at the beggining of the element?

You can use the filter function like this
let myarr = ['A511-0001-01', 'APWA-0001-03', 'APWA-9999-99'];

let filteredArray = myarr.filter(item => item.includes("AP"));

